# how to combine two LPCWSTRs?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, visual-c++

I have two variables that are `LPCWSTR`s. I want to create a new variable that will have the values of the first and second variable.
I tried this but it didn't work.

```
LPCWSTR d = L"sd";
LPCWSTR f = L"f";
LPCWSTR df = d + f;
```

I get this error when i try that.

```
1   IntelliSense: expression must have integral or enum type
```

Is there a function that can combine two `LPCWSTR`s?

Comment: So it's said, you expect the resulting string to be `L"sdf"`, somewhat like `strcat` would give you with `char` strings?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In C++ it is usually a good idea to use `std::string` for manipulations with strings. In your case it could look like:

```
LPCWSTR d = L"sd";
LPCWSTR f = L"f";
std::wstring df = std::wstring(d) + f;
LPCWSTR dfc = df.c_str(); // if you are really need this
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the C++ compiler cannot generate code to join together arrays.  The two strings in the example are arrays of type wchar_t.  To join arrays you must use higher level functions.  There are several ways of doing it:

```
LPWSTR df[20]; // cannot be LPCWSTR, because the C is for const.
wcsprintf(df, L"%s%s", d, f);
```

or

```
LPWSTR df[20];
wcscpy(df, d);
wcscat(df, f);
```

or use STL as previously answered.

Comment: Ack! `wcscpy` and `wcscat` are pure evil! Use the bounds-checked variants!

Comment: Ummm... you declared df as an array of 20 pointers to wide chars. I think you really want wchar_t df[20];  And Jonathan Grynspan's comment is 100% correct - stay away from wcscpy and wcscat, use wcscpy_s and wcscat_s instead.