# Read a registry value and concatenate

Tags: c++, windows, string, registry, concatenation

What's the simpler way, in C++, to read a registry string value and concatenate it with an existing string ?

Example : 
Read HKCU\Software\Classes.wav 's (default)

Concatenate this with "HKCU\Software\Classes\" in order to obtain a new LPWSTR?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493771/how-to-add-two-lpcwstr

Comment: thanks! and the simpler way to read a string from registry? (without having to FIRST read the length of the string, then malloc, etc. ... this is too long!!)

Comment: You have to first read the length of the string, then malloc, then read the string. There is no other way using the C API.

Comment: isn't there a ready-to-use fonction that reads a string from registry into LPWSTR ?

Comment: `LPWSTR` is actually `wchar_t *` - it is a pointer to a string of wide characters. Like with normal C strings, you have to deal with allocating the memory and reading into it yourself.

Comment: Why is there no easier method in C ?
Why do we have to allocate memory, read, delete memory *ourselves* ?

I can't imagine there is no library in 2012 that is ready-to-use.

**Do profesionnal programmers have time to spend on allocating memory, read string, delete etc.   each time they just want to use a very simple string?** ;)

I can't imagine there is no faster way !